# multi-dimensional grouping and sorting with crossfilter.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash, crossfilter

I am trying to refactor some data. It's an array of objects. I have looked at lodash's chaining functions and would accept answers using lodash but I wondered whether crossfilter is more appropriate. There could be 10000 to 100000 elements in this array.

1) The example of what I want to achieve is best described by saying that I end up with an array of objects that have been grouped by 'oJK' key but which have an array of the unique sorted prices for each 'oJK'. And that the array be sorted by the lowest (element[0]) of each objects prices array.

I have set up a jsfiddle with my example data/attempt:

[https://jsfiddle.net/handloomweaver/ffx9fgou/](http://jsfiddle.net/handloomweaver/ffx9fgou/)

If I do

```
cf = crossfilter();

cf.add(data);

price = cf.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.oJK;
});
```

groups = price.group().all();

i get:

```
[ { key: '420973:421065:20150801:1829137', value: 16 },
  { key: '420973:421065:20150801:1831518', value: 1 },
  { key: '420973:421065:20150801:1832059', value: 2 },
  { key: '420973:421065:20150801:1833610', value: 1 } ]
```

or if I do

```
price = cf.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.price;
});
groups = price.group().all();
```

I get

```
[ { key: 4400, value: 1 },
  { key: 4700, value: 1 },
  { key: 4900, value: 1 },
  { key: 5000, value: 1 },
  { key: 5100, value: 1 },
  { key: 5150, value: 1 },
  { key: 5300, value: 1 },
  { key: 5400, value: 3 },
  { key: 5430, value: 8 },
  { key: 5483, value: 2 } ]
```

Which groups on each 'oJK' or in second example on each 'price' but what I want is to like the first one (grouping on 'oJK') and then get each value price associated with that 'oJK' key sorted by lowest and the whole array sorted by lowest (element [0] of the prices array).

Sort of

```
[ { 'oJK': '420973:421065:20150801:1829137', 'prices': [4400, 4700, 4900, 5100, 5400, 5430, 5483]},
  { 'oJK': '420973:421065:20150801:1832059', 'prices': [5000, 5300] },
  { 'oJK': '420973:421065:20150801:1831518', 'prices': [5150] },
  { 'oJK': '420973:421065:20150801:1833610', 'prices': [5400]} ]
```

It seems a pretty complex example and I can't find anything similar I could learn from.

Comment: Is this for interactive visualization where you need to track these groupings as the user interacts with the visualization, or is it (as it sounds) a one-time refactor? If the later, then don't use Crossfilter for this, as it's meant for interactive data use-cases.

Comment: I should have said that it is an interactive ui. So this is one of the views but the user could switch to other views including by 'iJK'. I'm investigating crossfilter because i don't want to make a completely new array each time but maintain dimensional views

Comment: I'd not even use Crossfilter for different views, necessarily. Just if you need interactive filtering. If you do need that, then I'd say look at custom reducers in Crossfilter. Reductio is a helper library for building Crossfilter groups that supports this type of grouping using the sort-of-undocumented syntax reductio.valueList(value)(crossfilterGroup) - https://github.com/esjewett/reductio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use standard functions to do this. Something like

```
var map = {};
data.forEach(function(d) {
    if(map[d.oJK]) {
        map[d.oJK].push(d.price);
    } else {
        map[d.oJK] = [ d.price ];
    }
});

for(key in map) {
    map[key] = map[key].sort();
}
```

Here's a version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zkanp56y/